# Change page title after specific time when user on other tab with other website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to **change the title of my page after 1 minute**, when visitor change the tab and changed tab should contain other website (for eg. [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)) and title should flashes alternatively after every 2 seconds with 'original title'and 'changed title'.

case 1: when **0 product added to cart**, title of page should flashes with 'original title' and 'We miss you title'

case 2: When **1 or more products added into cart.** title of page should flashes alternatively 'original title' and '1 product in your cart title'

case 3: When visitor come to original tab flashing of title should stop and it should show original title only.

```
var cartCount = parseInt($('.cart-count').text()); // gives cart count
var currentDomain = (document.domain); // current domain
var pageTitle = $(document).find("head title").text(); // page title

// checking tab change

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() { 
  setTimeout(changeTitleFirst, 60000); // 1 minute timeout
  function changeTitleFirst(){
    setInterval(changeTitle, 2000);
    function changeTitle(){
      if(document.visibilityState === "hidden" && cartCount === 0){
          if(pageTitle !== "miss you"){
          $(document).find("head title").text("miss you");  
          } else {
          $(document).find("head title").text(pageTitle);
        }
      } 
      else if (document.visibilityState === "hidden" && cartCount > 0){
        if($(document).find("head title").text() !== "come back"){
           $(document).find("head title").text("come back");  
        } else {
          $(document).find("head title").text(pageTitle);
        }
      }
      else if (document.visibilityState !== "hidden"){
        $(document).find("head title").text(pageTitle);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }   
  }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise doing this. I can't speak for everyone, but if a tab tries to coax me back to it by flashing the title, I'm closing that tab.

Comment: Thank @Andrew for advise, this is my client's requirement and they have to implement it. Any help always welcome.

Comment: Well, I suppose your client has to give up this requirement, see how [timeouts in inactive tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) are behaving.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu Well, if I exclude the timeout from requirement and implement the rest of functionality, is it recommended?

Comment: What is said in the MDN article stands for the intervals too. Btw. What is your actual question? Are you facing troubles with the current code you have?

Comment: Yes, I am facing some issue with current code, its not checking cartCount sometimes so it leads to not excution of functionality, also sometimes when I navigate to other tab whole code is not functioning.